# Android supporting multiple resolution with multiple layout folder

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-resolution

Now I'm supporting multiple resolution with multiple layout folders.
I'm using android development studio and I made 3 different folders.

```
layout
layout-large-port-1280x720
layout-normal-port-800x480
```

and I tested on 800x480 and 1280x720. 480x800 worked well, but 1280x720 follow 800x480 folder's dp and UI.

I don't know why this thing happens to me and I don't know how to solve the problem. 
Why it doesn't work and what should I have to do?

Comment: guys I know that way. I just want to know how to set exact resolution for xml.
In my case, 800x480 xml is working on 1280x720 resolution. That's the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Different screen size, The following is a list of resource directories in an application that provides different layout designs for different screen sizes and different bitmap drawables for small, medium, high, and extra high density screens.

```
 res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
 res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
 res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
 res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
 res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

 res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
 res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
 res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

Thats code in the Manifest supports all dpis.

```
   <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" 
      android:normalScreens="true" 
      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:xlargeScreens="true"
      android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Comment: It's just 'How to set layout folder name' :p

Comment: so thats have the solution of perticular device layout. just create the `values` for the resolution `480x800` and the `values-sw720dp` for the resolution `1280x720` and not need the different layout resolution folder to be create just simply create the layout. its work well.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have given the corresponding drawables in drawable-xhdpi

I don't know on what basis you're creating the App. But it's better to avoid creating layout for specific screen sizes.. Instead you would give the following:

**layout-small-port** for devices like samsung galaxy y

**layout-normal-port** for devices like galaxy s2

**layout-large-port** for devices like nexus 7 which is 7 inch

**layout-xlarge-port** for devices having more than 7 inch size

*If you specify the screen size, you can't support more number of devices*

Comment: This is just another way to support various resolution. I want to set xml in exact resolution.

Answer (score 1):

U should use:

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For handsets (smaller than 480dp available width)
res/layout-sw480dp/main_activity.xml   # For phones (480dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
res/drawable – The default image folder
res/drawable-sw200dp
res/drawable-sw600dp
res/drawable-sw800dp
```