# Different layout folder for specific model

Tags: android, android-layout

I am currently testing on Samsung Galaxy S3 mini with resolution 800x480. I created a layout folder for this named `layout-800x480`. But when I start my App on Samsung Galaxy S3 mini then it takes the layout from `layout-normal` folder instead of `layout-800x480`.

**But why the device ignores folder layout-800x480?**

Comment: There is already an answer for that

[Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20765267/2187976

Comment: so it is just to make the change in manifest.xml and keep folder layout-800x480 ?

Comment: yeah and don't forget to create folers for small,large ... layout

Comment: "But why the device ignores folder layout-800x480?" -- 
because resolution-specific resources have not been supported in years. See [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) for supported resource set qualifiers.

Comment: yes but how would I make sure that the correct layout folder for resoulution 800x480 is chosen. I know the regular qualifier, but none of these would solve the problem, I guess.