# Creating Android Application for tablet

Tags: android, user-interface, tablet

I already have the source code for a mobile application in Android. Using that source code I want to create a tablet version for the same application. What are the steps that I can follow and what aspects should I keep in mind while making the UI for the tablet version?

Note : I have never made a tablet application before.

Comment: You just need to make all layouts according the size of tablet

Comment: you have code means you have functionality. you just have to make design for tablet. make changes in drawable .. make new drawable for tablet.. you can search on google for tablet design .. just keep the IDs same in tablet design

Comment: if the code for the tablet version the same like the mobile you must only adjust the ui. How you can achieve that, read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create app for all size you need should follow below point. It will help.

1. You need to create set you layout for all layout.
2. Ignore static value in your xml like margin, padding etc.
   if its necessary then use dimen.xml in your value folder.
3. Please refer below link of android:
   http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
4. If necessary then use image (png).
5. Try to use css(create xml) for selector and background. its auto manage for all layout.
6. Try to use 9 patch images.
7. Give support for all screen in manifest file

   ```
    < supports-screens 
            android:smallScreens="true" 
            android:normalScreens="true" 
            android:largeScreens="true"
            android:xlargeScreens="true"
            android:anyDensity="true" />
   ```

[Android supporting multiple resolution with multiple layout folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763322/android-supporting-multiple-resolution-with-multiple-layout-folder)

Tutorial: 
http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/different-layouts-for-different-screen-sizes-in-android/